# Using the python gdal module to open images in the same projection but different sizes

Tags: python, gdal, landsat

I'm not sure this is the correct site for this but,

I'm using the gdal.Open() module on python 2.7 to open Landsat GeoTIFF images.  They have the same UTM map projection, but different image sizes.

How do I fix the image sizes to be the same?  I'd like to make direct pixel-by-pixel comparisons.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/ is the place to ask this Q

Answer (score 0):

gdal_translate can be used simply to change the size of an image using the -outsize parameter, which takes two integer values as the xsize and ysize respectively, or two percentage values to scale the image. [see here](http://wiki.americaview.org/display/miview/Introduction+to+GDAL#IntroductiontoGDAL-ResizeanImage)

```
gdal_translate -outsize newxsize newysize imageFile outputFile
```

Comment: Are we sure this maintains an image's projection?  I loaded two before and after images and they didn't have the same values in the same UTM positions.

Comment: Yeah, no new metadata file (i.e. L71173062_06220101118_MTL.txt) was created for the translated image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reproject all rasters to the same raster shape/size. You can do this with [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to each raster file, e.g.:

```
gdalwarp -te xmin ymin xmax ymax -tr xres yres -r resampling_method srcfile dstfile
```

You can optionally replace `-tr` (target resolution) with `-ts width height` to specify the number of rows/columns.

The `-te` (target extents) and `-tr`/`-ts` (target resolution/size) options forces each of your source raster to have the same raster shape overlay, so you can correctly do a pixel-by-pixel comparison. You also need to choose a suitable `-r` [resampling method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling), depending on what your analysis is trying to achieve.